# How to pause app in simple way on android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make view of random text 3 times with time pausing between.
I just can't! It all run all together. I admit I don't know thread subject at all, I just need simple solution.

```
  public void loading3() {

      Random randomDouble = new Random();
      temp = (double) randomDouble.nextInt(100);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      result.setText(temp + "%");

    }
```

This is the code. I want to use it let's say 3-4 times in a row. How can i do it? I try inside loop or writing same methods in a row but it won't work because it doesn't wait for the first method to end before start the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You should not sleep on the main thread. This can easily be done with a `Handler` or `Timer`. Here is an example with a `Handler`:

```
private int mCount = 0;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mUpdater = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Random randomDouble = new Random();
        temp = (double) randomDouble.nextInt(100);
        result.setText(temp + "%");
        mCount++;

        if (mCount < 3)
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdater, 1000);
    }
}

public void loading3() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdater, 1000);
}
```